# 'text' Api is deprecated?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This is my code

[image]

I'm using Xcode6-Beta5 and want to define cell.text as String text from my array named msgHistory. Don't know what the problem is. and Is there anywhere I can find example codes of each class for swift language?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Another silly question is this ...

[image]

Don't have any idea why it bugs.

Comment: did you try `cell.textLabel.text`?

Comment: It show alert "Use of unresolved identifier 'textLabel' "

Comment: Just a note. Don't put screenshots of code into questions. Just copy and paste the code directly. It's much easier to read.

Comment: For the second part... read the error. It is now `[String]()` ... or `[String()]` can't remember which. But you can just click the red and white circle. It will auto fix it for you.

Comment: You really should be reusing your cells with `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SomeID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell` instead of continuously creating new ones.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text), `text` was deprecated in iOS 3.0. You are supposed to use `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` instead.